# How do I get a list of processes in a gnome-shell-extension?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I am writing a [gnome-shell-extension](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions) and I am trying to get a list of all the processes that are currently running. I have tried using **glibtop**, which has a function for retrieving processes [glibtop_get_proclist](http://developer.gnome.org/libgtop/stable/libgtop-proclist.html#glibtop-get-proclist), but the problem is, that this function returns a pointer to the list, so if I do:

```
let proclist = new GTop.glibtop_proclist;
pid_list = GTop.glibtop_get_proclist(proclist, 0, 0);
```

`pid_list` becomes of type number. Now javascript doesn't have pointer arithmetic, so I have no idea how I could access the list.

The `proclist` variable only contains a few number parameters such as `proclist total` and `proclist size`.

So how can I access the list that the `get_proclist` method returns? Or is there an easier way of getting a list of pids of running processes?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an idea of how to walk though the list you retrieved: [1](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/blob/master/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/extension.js)

Comment: I really wish it would, but all of the `glibtop` calls, that are used here, return their values in the 1st parameter buffer. The methods themselves return void. But the method, that I am trying to use, returns a pointer to the list that I want to access.